# Regular expression stripping $ in one string but not another

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use regular expressions to add php variables into an external html page so I can email is as html email in phpMailer

the string i'm trying to replace is:

```
<strong> %temp_pass%% </strong></p><p>
<a href="http://www.unlimitedtutors.com/forgotpass.php?email=%e%%&p=%myTempPass%%">
```

my regex is:

```
$hashTempPass = "$2a$10$";
$temp_pass = "'=$.hel3332lo\/'";
 $body = file_get_contents('email/forgot_pass_email.html');
 $forgot_pass_email = preg_replace('#[0-9A-Za-z.%]temp_pass%%#',$temp_pass, $forgot_pass_email);
$forgot_pass_email = preg_replace('#[0-9A-Za-z.%]myTempPass%%#',"$2a$10$", $forgot_pass_email);
```

The problem is that all of the $ and number symbols are stripped out of the myTempPass%%, but not from the temp_pass%% - its driving me crazy - what am i doing wrong? is it to do with the fact that myTempPass is in a url? how can i get it to include $/. in the replacement?

Comment: this is a really bad way of doing things, please research got "forgot password" feature should be implemented

Comment: ok, you got 1 input, 4 `preg_replace()` so where's the problem ? Can't you just give **one** input with **one** expected output ?

Comment: @teresko what is wrong with this method of forgot password? User clicks forgot password, I generate a new temporary password and send it to them along with the hashed pass in the url and when they click the link it activates, and then they log in and must change password immediately - I don't see the problem

Answer (score 1):

Your two strings

```
$hashTempPass = "$2a$10$";
$temp_pass = "'=$.hel3332lo\/'";
```

are interpolating `$2` and `$.` as variables.  You need to use single quotes to avoid interpolation.

```
$hashTempPass = '$2a$10$';
$temp_pass = '\'=$.hel3332lo\/\'';
```

Comment: even if I use the single quotes I'm still not getting the correct replacements - all I get is 'a2' for the myTemPass - but the strange thing is that the $temp_pass string shows up perfectly fine